# How to edit this function to exclude menu() in R?

Tags: r, function

Is there a way to edit this function (obtained from: https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues/355) so that it runs without having to select options 1, 2 or 3 from the following line: `menu(c("no", "yes", "copy a list with status_ids"))`? I.e. I just want the code to run with option 'no' selected, as the other two options are irrelevant for my purposes.

```
recover_stream <- function(path, dir = NULL, verbose = TRUE) {

  # read file and split to tweets
  tweets <- readLines(path, encoding = "UTF-8", warn = FALSE)
  tweets <- tweets[!tweets == ""]

  # write tweets to disk and try to read them in individually
  if (is.null(dir)) {
    dir <- paste0(tempdir(), "/tweets/")
    dir.create(dir)
  }

  if (verbose) {
    pb <- progress::progress_bar$new(
      format = "Processing tweets [:bar] :percent, :eta remaining",
      total = length(tweets), clear = FALSE
    )
    pb$tick(0)
  }

  tweets_l <- lapply(tweets, function(t) {
    pb$tick()
    id <- unlist(stringi::stri_extract_first_regex(t, "(?<=id\":)\\d+(?=,)"))[1]
    f <- paste0(dir, id, ".json")
    writeLines(t, f, useBytes = TRUE)
    out <- tryCatch(rtweet::parse_stream(f),
                    error = function(e) {})
    if ("tbl_df" %in% class(out)) {
      return(out)
    } else {
      return(id)
    }
  })

  # test which ones failed
  test <- vapply(tweets_l, is.character, FUN.VALUE = logical(1L))
  bad_files <- unlist(tweets_l[test])

  # Let user decide what to do
  if (length(bad_files) > 0) {
    message("There were ", length(bad_files),
            " tweets with problems. Should they be copied to your working directory?")
    sel <- menu(c("no", "yes", "copy a list with status_ids"))
    if (sel == 2) {
      dir.create(paste0(getwd(), "/broken_tweets/"))
      file.copy(
        from = paste0(dir, bad_files, ".json"),
        to = paste0(getwd(), "/broken_tweets/", bad_files, ".json")
      )
    } else if (sel == 3) {
      writeLines(bad_files, "broken_tweets.txt")
    }
  }

  # clean up
  unlink(dir, recursive = TRUE)

  # return good tweets
  return(dplyr::bind_rows(tweets_l[!test]))
}
```

Comment: Replace `sel <- menu(c("no", "yes", "copy a list with status_ids"))` with `sel <- 1`.

Comment: Could you not just delete everything below `# Let user decide what to do` relevant to selecting an option?

Comment: I did not carefully inspect the code. `menu(c("no", "yes", "copy a list with status_ids"))` returns `1` when you select no. So if you assign `sel <- 1` that will have the same affect. Your question was "I just want the code to run with option 'no' selected".